# Android Widget Broadcast Receiver, update Activity class automaticly

Tags: android, android-activity, android-widget, broadcastreceiver

I'm developing an android widget.
There is an integer on Widget Screen. For example min=100
When I make a call, I want this integer decrease 10.

I mean when I make a call the integer will be updated automaticly 90.

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make a receiver class to catch the outgoung call intents

```
<receiver android:name=".yourreceiver">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And
Update the widget in the onReceive

```
RemoteViews updateViews  =Update your min value and create the remote` view;
        // Update the widget 
        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, YourWidget.class);
        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, updateViews);
```